# Dual Monitor, Different Resolution Setup - Can I Use Just One For Gaming

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I am confused if I can do as I say or not. I am going to make by first ever Dual Monitor setup (**different resolution**, one 2k (for gaming) other 1080p). Here is what I am aiming for:

1. I want to use one monitor (out of the 2) exclusively for gaming and not both the monitors (as my GPU is not so powerful and **resolutions vary**).
2. Use both monitors for productivity related stuff (programming for e.g.)

On a dual monitor setup, is **Point 1** possible at all?

Thanks!

If it helps, the monitors are from separate brand, one costly and other really the cheapest. I want the good monitor for gaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily supported. The only issues you might encounter are:

1. The amount of memory on your video card won't support the resolutions you desire
2. The game might not remember the monitor it was opened on so you might have to move it to the correct monitor each time you run the game

Once you go dual monitors you will never go back :)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience games in full screen mode will always run on monitor #1 and ignore any other monitors.  Just make your big screen be #1 and you should get exactly what you want.

Personally, I'm running one nice monitor but the pixels are a bit small for maximum comfort, it's primarily used for games although I have to use it for TeamViewer also as none of my other monitors are big enough.  I have three other old but still good monitors that get most productivity-related tasks.